# Redis store json like document

Tags: redis

How to store following json object in redis database.

```
{"First":
[
 { "id": "5001", "type": "abc" },
 { "id": "5002", "type": "cde" },
 { "id": "5005", "type": "xyz" }
]
}
```

Comment: What had you tried and what is the problem?

Comment: You could look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16375188/redis-strings-vs-redis-hashes-to-represent-json-efficiency) discussion about cons and pros of different json storing methods in redis.