# how to optimize memory usage of sortedset in redis

Tags: memory, redis

use a sortedset to store a user's events :

```
zrangebyscore Fred -inf +inf withscores
1) "SEQNO20180607001"  [event's unique id]
2) "1514736000000"   [event's time, a unix timestamp]
3) "SEQNO20180607002"
4) "1514736000230"
5) "SEQNO20180607003"
6) "15147360002235"
```

and a simple key-value pair to store the event's details:

```
get SEQNO20180607001
"{\"name\":\"Fred\",\"age\":25,\"action\":\"click main page\"}"
```

like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16375188/redis-strings-vs-redis-hashes-to-represent-json-efficiency), the event detail, its value length isn't predictable, so I think 'hash' is not a good choice and I'm thinking about the sortedset's memory usage.Is there a good way to minimize the sortedset's memory usage? Thanks.

Comment: Do you realy need to store the timesamp? Can you use a simpe list and push event instead? Add timestamp in your json value if needed

Comment: with one list of events per user you will get the data in only one place

Comment: I need to get a user's events in a specific time range very quickly(like 'select ... where user=Fred and time between xxx and yyy'), so I think I have to store the timestamp